# Webpack4 witch webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: webpack

Я использовал webpack 3 и хочу перенести проект в webpack 4. 
теперь я использую `optimization.splitChunks`.Но получаю ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        entry: {
            admin_app: exposePath('AdminApp', 'Components'),
            user_app: exposePath('UserApp', 'Components')
        },
        output: {
            path: paths.CLIENT_BUILD_PATH,
            filename: '[name].client.bundle.js',
            sourceMapFilename: 'maps/[name].client.map.js',
            chunkFilename: "chunks/[name].client.chunk.js"
        },
        /*plugins: [                                                  //  plugins from webpack 3
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                minChunks: function (module) {
                    return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'manifest',
                minChunks: Infinity
            })
        ]
        */
        optimization: {         // so the code will be written on top (Webpack 4)
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: 'vendor',
                        test(module) {
                            return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
                        }
                    },

                    manifest: {
                        name: 'manifest',
                        minChunks: Infinity
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всю оптимизацию команда `webpack` вынесла в свойство `optimization`. Свойство `splitChunks` задает конфигурацию для поиска модулей, которые используются несколькими модулями, чанкирует этот модуль в отдельный файл, чтобы уменьшить дублирование:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...,

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test(module) {
                        return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
                    }
                },

                manifest: {
                    minChunks: Infinity
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`webpack` позволяет вынести `shared` модули в отдельные чанки с помощью поля `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups`. Чанкирование также производится по умолчанию в продакшн моде.

Comment: Я скопипастил ваше решение но у меня возникли проблемы.

Comment: понял , спасибо большое . Буду разбираться